# Python scraping delete duplicates

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, duplicates, screen-scraping

I dont wanna have a email address twice, with this code I get the error
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
So i assume that the line
    allLinks= set() 
is wrong and I have to use a tuple and not a list, is that right?

Thats my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
def get_emails(_links:list):

for i in range(len(_links)):
 new_d = soup(requests.get(_links[i]).text, 'html.parser').find_all('a', {'class':'my_modal_open'})
 if new_d:
   yield new_d[-1]['title']


start = 20
while True:
d = soup(requests.get('http://www.schulliste.eu/type/gymnasien/?bundesland=&start={page_id}'.format(page_id=start)).text, 'html.parser')
results = [i['href'] for i in d.find_all('a')][52:-9]
results = [link for link in results if link.startswith('http://')]



next_page=d.find('div', {'class': 'paging'}, 'weiter')

if next_page:

    start+=20

else:
    break

allLinks= set() 

if results not in allLinks:


    print(list(get_emails(results)))

    allLinks.add(results)
```

Comment: That's right. A list cannot be used as a key in a dict or a value in a set. You have to convert the list to a tuple. But keep in mind that `(1, 2, 3) != (2, 1, 3)`, so that's something to be careful of.

Comment: you probably want to `update` the set rather than `add` items to it

Comment: How do i do this?

Comment: @radonrace search for "update" in : https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects

Comment: ok but that does not solve the list-tuple problem right?

Comment: a tuple or in this case a string with valid delimiter will also work. List cannot be used in this case as they cannot be hashed

Comment: thanks, but I dont know how to use the tuple in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add an entire list of emails as a single entry in the `set`.

What you want is to add the actual emails each one in a separate `set` entry.

The problem is in this line:

```
allLinks.add(results)
```

It adds the entire `results` list as a single element in the `set` and that doesn't work. Use this instead:

```
allLinks.update(results)
```

This will update the `set` with elements from the `list`, but each element will be a separate entry in the `set`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working but I still get duplicate emails.

```
    allLinks = []

if results not in allLinks:


    print(list(get_emails(results)))

    allLinks.append((results))
```

Does anybody know why?